# Inputs y validación en python

Tags: python, validación, herencia, class, input

Estoy intentado hacer que por consola se ingresen 8 números enteros (validados que solo sean positivos), pero que pueda volver a intentar el ingreso si dicha función no se cumple. Pero al hacerlo como el codigo de abajo que tengo, solo puedo ingresar 8 números, 8 intentos, ya sean fallidos o no. Y también imprimir los 8 números enteros positivos, solo me muestra 1.

```
for i in range(8):
   nro=int(input("Número: "))
   if nro<0:
       print("Ingrese de nuevo el número")
       

print(nro, end=", ")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo me deja ingresar 8, cuando debieron sen 9 en ese ejemplo ya que uno fue fallido, y solo me muestra el último en vez de todos los correctos ingresados.
Como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Necesitas dos bucles anidados. El de fuera se repite 8 veces (uno para cada dato que debes pedir). El de dentro se repite **hasta que** el número introducido por el usuario sea correcto (este segundo bucle, al no tener un número predeterminado de veces, debería ser un bucle `while`)

Comment: @abulafia como quedaría en código? ya lo hice pero me da error de un bucle infinito    .Lo tengo así                                                                     for i in range(8):
    nro=int(input("Número: "))
    while(nro<0):
        print("Ingrese de nuevo el número")

    
       
print(nro, end=", ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque ya tienes una buena respuesta, para completar, te escribo aquí el enfoque que te proponía en el comentario. El intento que hiciste está mal porque no vuelves a pedir el número al usuario cuando lo introduce mal. Es decir, hace falta otro `input()` dentro del `while`.

```
for i in range(8):
  n = int(input("Número:"))
  while n<0:
    print("Número no válido. Ingréselo de nuevo")
    n = int(input("Número: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que llevar la cuenta a mano, e incrementarla sólo cuando el número sea positivo. Los valores los vas agregando a una lista inicialmente vacia:

```
i = 0
lista = []
while i < 8:
    nro = int(input("Número: "))
    if nro < 0:
        print("Ingrese de nuevo el número")
    else:
        lista.append(nro)
        i += 1

print(lista)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!